# Converting date time format in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

How do I convert the following date into the dd/mm/yyyy format?

```
Tue Aug  4 17:05:41 2015
```

I tried multiple things and options, but no luck.

```
$a = Get-Date -UFormat %c
(Get-Date $a).ToString("ddMMyyyy")
```

This dateformat was found in a log file and my system datetime format is dd/mm/yyyy.
I am trying to do a comparison between them. So, I need to change the date time format.

Comment: For comparison, you should better compare `DateTime` objects themselves, not their `toString()` representations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If possible please provide me some details about it

Comment: Just that, you create a `DateTime` object out of a substring via `get-date -format "dd\/MM\/yyyy"`, create another object based on current date, then compare like integers. `if ($onedate -lt $twodate) {...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer from @jisaak is *almost* spot on, except for the fact that the extra padding space in front of the date component ("Tue Aug  **4** 17:05:41 2015") is going to cause an error when you try to parse a date between the 10th and 31st of the month:

```
PS C:\> [Datetime]::ParseExact('Tue Aug  4 17:05:41 2015', 'ddd MMM  d HH:mm:ss yyyy', $us)

Tuesday, August 04, 2015 5:05:41 PM


PS C:\> [Datetime]::ParseExact('Tue Aug 11 17:05:41 2015', 'ddd MMM  d HH:mm:ss yyyy', $us)
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ [Datetime]::ParseExact('Tue Aug 11 17:05:41 2015', 'ddd MMM  d HH:mm:ss yyyy', $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

The easiest way to go about this is to remove the padding space in both the input string and the format string:

```
function Parse-CustomDate {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$DateString,
        [string]$DateFormat = 'ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy',
        [cultureinfo]$Culture = $(New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo -ArgumentList "en-US")
    )

    # replace double space by a single one
    $DateString = $DateString -replace '\s+',' '

    [Datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, $DateFormat, $Culture)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe primitive, but it does the job :)

```
$Date = 'Tue Aug  4 17:05:41 2015' -split "\s"
$Year = $Date[-1]
$Time = $Date | ? {$_ -match "..:..:.."}
$DayName = $Date[0]
$Day = $Date[3]
$Month = $Date[1]

Get-Date "$Month $Day $Year $Time" -Format "ddMMyyy"

04082015
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't want to use -split. but thanks. voted up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Datetime [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=VS.110).aspx) method:

```
$us = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo("en-US")
[Datetime]::ParseExact('Tue Aug  4 17:05:41 2015', 'ddd MMM  d HH:mm:ss yyyy', $us)
```

As Vesper mentioned, you are now able to compare datetime objects.

Comment: This is going to fail from the 10th to the 31st of each month, due to the double space in front of the date (`d`) component.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Get-Date -format d
```

This will give you today's date, but in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. Be careful though; this will give you a `string` and not an `integer`.