# powershell assistance data extraction

Tags: database, powershell, date, extract, dump

I have a data ware house file dumped in a network share. so i cannot do a lot of  pre manipulation, so i need to extract the date out of each line, where each line the date always starts with a ", then the 8 "character" date in this format 19990312 which is  yyyyddmm and i need to have a powershell "way " to extract the date to the format of  mm/dd/yyyy. Each line varies in lengtha little but it is always the last 8 "characters" of line  is  the date below is a sample  odf the file. any assistance would be greatly  appreciated

```
"920:Bob Bikes                                   ",19870707
"2471:CAMPBEL                                       ",19971010
"2480:PARADISE cookis                                               ",19990720
"2481:CAFE                                               ",20050720
"2481:PARAE                                               ",20050720
"2482: BONES                                                   ",20050720
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you have an issue with the process that imports the data? That is where you should be fixing this.

Answer (score 3):

The extraction part of your question is similar to [Read line-by-line file and split values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616414/read-line-by-line-file-and-split-values)

So let's put your sample line of text into file.txt, and break it apart based on the commas, to get the sixth part as your date field:

```
$yourdate = Get-Content -Delimiter "," -Path file.txt
$yourdate[6]
```

This results in 20050720

The second part of your question is similar to [converting date time format in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808296/converting-date-time-format-in-powershell)

So you want to set that string as a date, and then format that date to the way you want:

```
[Datetime]::ParseExact($yourdate[6], 'yyyymmdd', $us) | Get-Date -UFormat "%m/%d/%Y"
```

Your final result is:
01/20/2005

This is initially explained in a way that is is easier to understand the 6th part when reading through the code. However, if the number of parts vary, and the date  is not always the sixth part, @TheMadTechnician is correct, and you can reference the last part as $yourdate[-1].

So the last line would look like this instead:

```
[Datetime]::ParseExact($yourdate[-1], 'yyyymmdd', $us) | Get-Date -UFormat "%m/%d/%Y"
```

Comment: Even better than assuming there are 6 fields, since he says it is always the last one use `$yourdate[-1]`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Great point, to call out the assumption of 6 parts. I've accounted for that in the answer now. TY

Comment: Thank you all very much for the  greta answers  now I get to implement it, keep your fingers crossed please ty